# How to assign a calendar event with C # in Hotmail/Outlook?

Tags: javascript, c#, calendar

And I wish the following objective:
assign an event to the hotmail calendar

I have the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Live; 

private void editEvent()
{

        try
        {
            var authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
            LiveLoginResult result = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.calendars", "wl.calendars_update" });

            if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                var eventToPost = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                eventToPost.Add("name", "program my c# - 2nd trial");

                eventToPost.Add("calendar_id", "calendar.136c10ca65544801.99c35f9a9fb341a3af35daa82f4569f8");

                eventToPost.Add("description", "this should be 2nd calendar");
                eventToPost.Add("start_time", "2019-09-10T01:30:00-08:00");
                eventToPost.Add("end_time", "2019-09-12T03:00:00-08:00");
                eventToPost.Add("location", "business placeeeeeee");
                eventToPost.Add("is_all_day_event", false);
                eventToPost.Add("availability", "busy");
                eventToPost.Add("visibility", "public");

                this.session = result.Session;

                connected = true;
                this.connectClient = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);

                var meResult = await connectClient.PutAsync("event.136c10ca6a355671.5f21a7994c7e40fd800bc48dcc07300b.991d1912ec6b4523a0f08839992aa2bb", eventToPost);

                meData = meResult.Result;
            }
        }
        catch (LiveAuthException ex)
        {
            // Display an error message.
        }
        catch (LiveConnectException ex)
        {
            // Display an error message.
            infoTextBlock.Text += ex.Data + " ..." + ex.Message;
        }

}
```

In which I try to test it to see how it works and if it fulfills the desired objective.

But I do not know which library works LiveAuthClient and LiveConnectSessionStatus

Download the nuget package live sdk package, but it still shows error in LiveAuthClient and LiveConnectSessionStatus

I would like to know which library should download to test its operation, since I want to add an event to the Hotmail calendar with C # or Javascript. If anyone knows, or if you have an example, I would greatly appreciate it.